# Отваливается воркер после деплоя

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

После очередного деплоя отваливается задача sidekiq.

Ошибка: `NameError: uninitialized constant DeliveryWorker`

в контроллере вызывается `DeliveryWorker.perform_async(@invoice.id)`

файл `delivery_worker.rb` расположен в папке `app/workers`

команда `puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` говорит о том, что в автозагрузку `app/workers` попадает.

Т.е. по факту сейчас воркер работает. Но только после того, как я перезапустил `sidekiq`.

Остальные воркеры не отваливаются.

В чем может быть причина того, что воркер отваливается? куда можно посмотреть?

P.S.Эта ошибка должна отработать в контроллере же, я правильно понимаю? ведь DeliveryWorker в контроллере. Т.е. отображаться не в логах sidekiq, а в логах приложения.

Comment: Вы не могли ошибиться в названии DeliveryWorker в delivery_worker.rb?

Comment: нет, это точно.